# Naming Terminal Tabs in .vimrc not completely working

Tags: vim

I am using Vim in iTerm3.

This mostly works:

```
let &titlestring = @% 
set title
```

However, I can't figure out why when I open my .vimrc I don't get ".vimrc". Instead, I get a generic tab name.

I'm familiar with ":help tabline", but the example was long, complicated, and didn't work to modify the tab name at all.

I've also tried "set titlestring=%f" but it also appears to have no effect.

Comment: Have you tried auto-commands?

Comment: I have, but I am unclear how that would improve this situation. This is loading file names, which suggests it is running automatically and at the appropriate time. My best guess is that there is something specific about the .vimrc file type which this doesn't account for.

Answer (score 0):

It's because vim sets the `'titlestring'` around the time of the `VimEnter` autocmd (although I am not sure exactly when it sets it, it appears to be after your vimrc is loaded).

I found this, for example, to work well if I put it in my vimrc and opened vim normally:

```
autocmd VimEnter,DirChanged * let &titlestring = v:servername . '  ' . getcwd()
```

This does what you seek (now when you open vim, the `&titlestring` variable is set *after your system-wide vimrc sets it*) with the added benefit of adding the directory after you `:cd <somewhere>`; feel free to remove the last bit.

Another option is to read `:help 'titlestring'`.

---

If you just want the tabs to have better names, then see `:help 'guitablabel'` or use [a plugin](https://github.com/mkitt/tabline.vim).